# Issues cross-compiling on WSL2 -> RISCV in order to simulate with GEM5

Tags: ubuntu, cross-compiling, wsl-2, riscv, gem5

sorry if i'm a newbie and maybe i didn't used the interface properly.
I'm developing a project for uni where i have to simulate a RISCV-based OoO CPU executing a C benchmark.
As Gem5 have to be compiled and ran on Linux, but VMs were too slow, i decided to use WSL2 included in Windows11, with Ubuntu-22.04. I cloned the git repository and successfully compiler gem5 for RISCV architecture. However, the problem is not with Gem5 apparently: when i run my script, the compilation of the main.c (benchmark) fails, not generating the .elf file and reporting this:

```
alessandro@DESKTOP-B2O2HHH:/opt/ase_riscv_gem5_sim$ /sudo ./simulate.sh -i ./programs/my_c_benchmark/ -nogui
Simulating my_c_benchmark
Compiling program my_c_benchmark
CLEAN my_c_benchmark.elf obj/main.o
/usr/bin/riscv64-linux-gnu-gcc-11 $OPTIMIZATION_FLAGS -mcmodel=medlow  -march=rv64g -mabi=lp64d  -static -Wall -Wextra -D_GEM5_ -I$GEM5_SRC/include -I$GEM5_SRC/include/gem5/asm/generic -nostartfiles  -T./linker.ld  -lc -L$CC_INSTALLATION_PATH/lib -c -o obj/main.o main.c
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:26:21: warning: variable ‘v7’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
   26 |     volatile double v7[N];
      |                     ^~
/usr/bin/riscv64-linux-gnu-gcc-11 -o $program.elf   $GEM5_SRC/util/m5/src/abi/riscv/m5op.S ./crt0.S  obj/main.o  $OPTIMIZATION_FLAGS -mcmodel=medlow  -march=rv64g -mabi=lp64d  -static -Wall -Wextra -D_GEM5_ -I$GEM5_SRC/include -I$GEM5_SRC/include/gem5/asm/generic -nostartfiles  -T./linker.ld  -lc -L$CC_INSTALLATION_PATH/lib
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/riscv64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../riscv64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc-cross/riscv64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../riscv64-linux-gnu/lib/libc.a(libc-start.o): in function `.L0 ':
(.text+0x4): undefined reference to `__fini_array_start'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/riscv64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../riscv64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: (.text+0xc): undefined reference to `__fini_array_end'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/riscv64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../riscv64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: (.text+0x15e): undefined reference to `__ehdr_start'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/riscv64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../riscv64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: (.text+0x2a6): undefined reference to `__preinit_array_start'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/riscv64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../riscv64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: (.text+0x2ae): undefined reference to `__preinit_array_end'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/riscv64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../riscv64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: (.text+0x2da): undefined reference to `__init_array_start'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/riscv64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../riscv64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: (.text+0x2e2): undefined reference to `__init_array_end'
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/riscv64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../riscv64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: my_c_benchmark.elf: hidden symbol `__fini_array_end' isn't defined
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/riscv64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../riscv64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:38: $program.elf] Error 1
Simulating program my_c_benchmark
/opt/gem5/build/RISCV/gem5.opt --debug-flags=O3PipeView,O3CPUAll  --debug-file=/opt/ase_riscv_gem5_sim/results/my_c_benchmark/trace.out --outdir=/opt/ase_riscv_gem5_sim/results/my_c_benchmark/ --verbose  ./gem5/riscv_o3_custom.py --caches  -c ./programs/my_c_benchmark//my_c_benchmark.elf --directory=/opt/ase_riscv_gem5_sim/results/my_c_benchmark  --errout=/opt/ase_riscv_gem5_sim/results/my_c_benchmark/programm.err
gem5 Simulator System.  https://www.gem5.org
gem5 is copyrighted software; use the --copyright option for details.

gem5 version 23.0.1.0
gem5 compiled Nov 16 2023 15:48:41
gem5 started Nov 16 2023 16:02:12
gem5 executing on DESKTOP-B2O2HHH, pid 23025
command line: /opt/gem5/build/RISCV/gem5.opt --debug-flags=O3PipeView,O3CPUAll --debug-file=/opt/ase_riscv_gem5_sim/results/my_c_benchmark/trace.out --outdir=/opt/ase_riscv_gem5_sim/results/my_c_benchmark/ --verbose ./gem5/riscv_o3_custom.py --caches -c ./programs/my_c_benchmark//my_c_benchmark.elf --directory=/opt/ase_riscv_gem5_sim/results/my_c_benchmark --errout=/opt/ase_riscv_gem5_sim/results/my_c_benchmark/programm.err

warn: The `get_runtime_isa` function is deprecated. Please migrate away from using this function.
Simulating until tick=18446744073709551615
src/base/loader/image_file_data.cc:110: fatal: fatal condition fd < 0 occurred: Failed to open file /opt/ase_riscv_gem5_sim/programs/my_c_benchmark/my_c_benchmark.elf.
This error typically occurs when the file path specified is incorrect.
Memory Usage: 108208 KBytes
```

Apparently the problem is that the cross-compiler doesn't find some libraries, as we can point that the error message start with

```
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/riscv64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../riscv64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc-cross/riscv64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../riscv64-linux-gnu/lib/libc.a(libc-start.o): in function `.L0 ':
(.text+0x4): undefined reference to `__fini_array_start'
...
...
my_c_benchmark.elf: hidden symbol `__fini_array_end' isn't defined
/usr/lib/gcc-cross/riscv64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../riscv64-linux-gnu/bin/ld: final link failed: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

and so the compilation fails. This error seems to propagate to the simulator, as the `.elf` file is no longer found, as written at the end of the output log. I don't know if my interpretation is good, but i need help solving this (problably WSL2 is not recommended i know, as Windows messes with the build process, but i can only use WSL2).

I don't know if it's a good idea using the riscv toolchain for windows instead of the linux one, as integrating it in WSL may make a mess (?)